# How to play audio file continuously if user switched to another module of app in ios?

Tags: html, ios, audio, webview

I'm doing one webview app for ios. In that im using html pages and UIWebview. I have somany modules in that app. in that, im playing one audio file using html code and UIWebview.
My Issue is while user plays the audio file, if he wont stop the audio, once he switched to the another feature of the same app the audio is stopping.
I'm using following code

In appdelegate.m

```
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL ok;
    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    ok = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                             error:&setCategoryError];
    if (!ok) {NSLog(@"%s setCategoryError=%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, setCategoryError);
    }
```

Also I added code for Required background modes app plays audio

still im facing same issue, audio not playing continuously while user switched to another feature of the same app. Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: Try using https://github.com/nicklockwood/SoundManager

Comment: i tried with soundmanager but not working bro